# Program crashes with fclose

Tags: c, pointers, fclose

I am working with the following text file: https://mega.nz/#!EN4iRJxA!VtKFEl9dlQHWHIzcgfOfpXTt9_ill_YkgsLWL3nORLg
And the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct
    {
        int id;
        char lastname[25];
        char name[20];
        float average;
    }student;

    int main(){
        int i;
        student *pointer= (student*) malloc(3);

        FILE *file= fopen("Struct.txt", "r");
        fread(pointer, sizeof(student), 3, file);
        for(i= 0; i< 3; i++){
            printf("Id: %d\nName: %s\nLast name: %s\nAverage: %.2f\n",
                (pointer+ i) -> id,
                (pointer+ i) -> name,
                (pointer+ i) -> lastname,
                (pointer+ i) -> average);
        }
        fclose(file);
        system("pause");
        return 0;   
    }
```

When I delete the fclose function it works but I checked it and seems to be correct. What am I missing?

Comment: Your malloc is a disaster:(

Comment: The file `struct.txt` from the download link is anything but a text file.  Two thirds (119 out of 168)  bytes are null bytes; text files do not contain any null bytes.

Comment: I don't know why, a previously program saved it that way. I think it is correct as this program reads it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your `fclose`, instead you need to fix two things:

- You need to check the return error of `fopen`:

  ```
  if( NULL == file )
  {
      printf( "Cannot open\n" );
      exit( 1 );
  }
  ```
- Your malloc code doesn't look right, should be:
  `student *pointer= malloc(3 * sizeof(student));`

Comment: `student *pointer= (student*) malloc(3 * sizeof(student));` should be `student *pointer= malloc(3 * sizeof(student));`

Comment: ok I see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

thanks

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but if I delete the cast my compiler complains and doesn't compile.

Comment: what compiler do you use? It should work, see another duplicate Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798608/c-pointer-memory-allocation

Answer (score 3):

Your program isn't allocating memory the way you think it is. malloc(3) [returns three bytes of memory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html). Most likely the file pointer is immediately after it in memory

```
[ | | ][*FILE]
```

When you read in the file, the data first goes in to the three bytes of memory you've allocated. But since it doesn't fit, it keeps going and overwrites the memory containing the pointer to the file too.

```
[student data student data]
```

Then calling `fclose` closes the file at `dat` or whatever was read in from the file. This is a programming error, sometimes called a "wild pointer dereference", and if the data read in doesn't point to something that can be closed like a file can (as is happening to you) the program will crash.

The fixes suggested by artm should resolve your problem, but I thought this explanation might help you understand why you saw the crash.

Comment: Yes it helped a lot. Thank you for your effort and time!