# C - Pointer memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, allocation

Can someone please explain to me the difference between

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

&&

```
int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Thanks!

Comment: `malloc` returns a void pointer. As you are assigning it to `int` pointer, it's always good to type cast. It won't make any difference in code but you will avoid one warning.

Comment: @Swanand, you will not get any warning if you don't type caste the return of `malloc()`.

Comment: Its compiler dependent. eg, If you are writing  `C` program in a `C++` compiler, then you need to cast.

Comment: @Swanand `malloc`'s return  is `void*`, this means that in `C` there is no need to `cast` `malloc`, but if you need to do that probably is because you are using `a wrong Compiler` or maybe the `wrong Language`. Now, could you please explain us why **it's always good to type cast.**? Trust me, there will be a big difference at some point by doing that. Please explain.

Comment: @Haris & @ Milchi Yes... You both are correct. My compiler is wrong. I tried with GCC and it was without any warning. I am using an eclipse based compiler with lot of saftey plugins (MISRA, Lint etc) that's why I got warning.

Comment: @Swanand [Please take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545365/why-does-this-code-segfault-on-64-bit-architecture-but-work-fine-on-32-bit).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you are casting the return of `malloc()` in the second example. `malloc()` returns a `void*` pointer, which is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type in this case.

Therefore casting in this case is not required and should not be done. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).